# Query doesn't insert into table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I using a register form and i would like to see if i have missing columns/tables. I'm using `var_dump $stmt;` and `echo $e->getMessage();`

Every time I get successfully message but the code doesn't insert anything into the database .

If I'm using `echo $e->getMessage();` I get this:

> object(PDOStatement)#11 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(153) "INSERT INTO bg_user(user_id, passwd, email, account_status) VALUES(:login, :password, :email, :status)" }
> Notice: Undefined variable: e in include\classes\user.php on line 89
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getMessage() on null in include\classes\user.php:89 Stack trace:
> #0 include\functions\register.php(57): USER->register('test123', 'a3876fafbc8b9b9...', 'test@tex.com', NULL)
>
> #1 pages\register.php(11): include('D:\Working Stat...')
> #2 index.php(199): include('D:\Working Stat...')
> #3 {main} thrown in include\classes\user.php on line 89

This is my code:

```
public function register($username,$password,$email,$ref)
{
    global $safebox_size;
    
    try
    {
        $password = md5($password);
        $social_id = rand(1000000, 9999999);
        $status = "OK";
        
        $stmt = $this->account->prepare("INSERT INTO bg_user(user_id, passwd, email, account_status) 
                                                   VALUES(:login, :password, :email, :status)");
                                              
        $stmt->bindparam(":login", $username);
        $stmt->bindparam(":password", $password);
        $stmt->bindparam(":email", $email);
        $stmt->bindparam(":status", $status);
        
        $stmt->execute();
        
        
        $lastId = $this->account->lastInsertId();
        $safebox_password = "000000";
        
        $stmt = $this->player->prepare("INSERT INTO safebox(account_id, size, password) 
                                                   VALUES(:account_id, :size, :password)");
                                              
        $stmt->bindparam(":account_id", $lastId);
        $stmt->bindparam(":size", $safebox_size);
        $stmt->bindparam(":password", $safebox_password);
            
        $stmt->execute();
        
        if($ref && count(getAccountInfo($ref)))
            addReferral($lastId, $ref);
        
        return $stmt;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        //echo $e->getMessage();
        print 'ERROR';
    }
}
```

My question is: what command do I have to use for var_dump, echo, print etc. to report errors (missing columns or tables)?

Comment: Sounds like you're doing it outside the `catch`

Comment: Post the actual code that's getting the error, not the version with the code commented out.

Comment: just added echo $e->getMessage(); after  $stmt->execute();.

Comment: the problem is , im getting NULL there and i dont know how to see missing collumns or tables.

Comment: It needs to be inside `catch (PDOException $e)` -- where you currently have it commented out.

Comment: but even like that, i dont get any error message. only success (but query dosent insert into db)

Comment: Did you enable `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`?

Comment: where should i do that ? sorry im new on pdo

Comment: When you create the PDO object.

Comment: See the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)

Comment: `class Database
{
 public $conn;
 
 public function dbConnection($host, $db_name, $user, $password, $sqlite=null)
 {
  $this->conn = null;    
  try
  {
   if($sqlite==null)
    $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $db_name, $user, $password) ;
   else
   {
$this->conn = new PDO("sqlite:include/db/site.db");
$this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   }
  }
catch(PDOException $exception)
  {
   global $offline;
   $offline = 1;
   echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
  }
  
  return $this->conn;
 }
}`

Comment: That looks right.

Comment: What are `$this->account` and `$this->player` in the `USER` class? Shouldn't there just be a single `connection` property?

Comment: they are databse names

Comment: But `prepare()` is a PDO method.

Comment: ` public function __construct($host, $user, $password)
 {
  $database = new Database();
  
  $account = $database->dbConnection($host, "data1", $user, $password);
  $this->account = $account;
  
  $player = $database->dbConnection($host, "data2", $user, $password);
  $this->player = $player;
  
  $common = $database->dbConnection($host, "data1", $user, $password);
  $this->common = $common;
  
  $sqlite = $database->dbConnection("", "", "", "", "yes");
  $this->sqlite = $sqlite;
  
  $log = $database->dbConnection($host, "data1", $user, $password);
  $this->log = $log;
    }`

Comment: i using multi db (3 dbs)

Comment: Please stop putting code into the comments. [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70058604/edit) when adding new detail